# PHP Unit Testing farmeworks suggestion

Tags: php, unit-testing, compare

I am pretty new in php . I wanted to know which unit testing framework for php is more suitable among developers. For its easy learning and management curve.

Comment: I don't usually tell people "Google it", but really, how is anyone else supposed to know what you consider suitable, easy, or will be adequate for your use case? I could guess, but then we'd be making a list of php unit testing frameworks, which is probably already the subject of tens of blogs one could locate by searching the internet.

Comment: I believe Stack over flow is a site to ask about questions  from regular developers . Please don't bother . There must be someone who will be really happy to help . Thanks ... Regards -- Mahabub Islam

Comment: This site is for asking about programming problems with objective solutions. It is not a personal research assistant. I am not trying to be combative, but you'll find this question won't remain open in its current form because it is off-topic, too broad, and opinion-based. Good luck with your research, though :)

Comment: yeah I can see that... still gotta learn a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think PHPUNIT does this job pretty perfectly. Its also easy to learn, and of course I appreciate your interest to learn unit testing though you are new in php. You can checkout PHPUNIT here
https://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

Me personally, I use Notepad++ for everything coding and then I test on the server I am working with. And I watch for any errors by adding this to the top of scripts in development:

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

When I am done, I turn it off as to not to exploit any information for potential hackers.